# how to do the arithmetic operations on a list of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataframe with a column that has a list of dictionaries.
It looks something like this:

```
[{'item_cd': '9999999999', 'width': 18.0, 'depth': 12.0, 'height': 2.0 }, {'item_cd': '8888888888', 'width': 10.0, 'depth': 7.0, 'height': 2.4}]
```

I was looking for an efficient way of finding the:

- height: sum of 2 smallest heights in order
- min of (sum of 2 smallest widths in order, max of depth in order)

I was trying to do some sorting using this logic. But I guess there is something wrong with my approach.

```
lst = list(zip(*[sorted(d.items()) for d in input_list]))
```

I would appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Do you in fact have a dataframe? If your question is about Pandas, then you should explicitly use that tag for the question (and not the `dictionary` tag) and show a complete example (i.e., include the relevant `import`s and the setup code to create the DataFrame). If not, then don't call it that - if you're working with a list of dicts, then say that you're working with a list of dicts.

Comment: ... That being said, a pandas dataframe with lists of dictionaries *doesnt make much sense* and would be pretty useless. Probably it would make sense to create some native python data structure if you want to manipulate it, or, create *a dataframe from the list of dicts...*

Comment: Ah, I think I see - you have a column where each individual cell value is a dict, such that the overall column is a Series of dicts?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes! The column is a series of dicts.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely just make a dataframe from that series, and then operate on that normally using builtins like `.min` etc.